# SQL date format query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert a data into a table, but I face a problem in date syntax, I need to present the year with 4 digit.

This is what I have done:

```
create table ee  
(
    empno number(3), 
    ename VARCHAR2(24), 
    sal number(4), 
    hiredate Date
);

Insert into ee (empno, ename, sal, hiredate)
Values (200, 'Ahmed', 4000, to_date('01/01/2008', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

and the result is that (01-JAN-08)

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your syntax is fine.  How are you determining the "format" of the date output?

Comment: I test it in sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is fine.  That is just the default format for query results.  That said, I would recommend a date constant:

```
Insert into ee (empno, ename, sal, hiredate)
    Values (200, 'Ahmed', 4000, date '2008-01-01');
```

If you want to see the result differently, you can use `to_char()`:

```
to_char(hiredate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: I have got the same result , still the year with 2 digit

Comment: @DoaaAljammal . . . As the answer explains, the data is fine.  That is just the default format for displaying dates.  You can use `to_char()` to convert to a string.

Comment: `                                                                                                                                                         insert into ff (empno, ename, sal, hiredate)
Values (200, 'k', 400, to_char('01/JAN/2008', 'DD/MMM/yyyy'));                                                `  is that what u mean?

Comment: @DoaaAljammal . . . No.  The insert is fine.  When you want to retrieve the data, you can convert it to a string to see the format you want.

Comment: @DoaaAljammal Oracle doesn't even have a date column type that stores years without century. You're possibly confusing the actual value (stored in whatever internal format Oracle sees fit) and the result of the default date to string conversion made by your client tool when you retrieve a value.